# Is there a way to know when a recent app started?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing an application which monitors the recent apps started or more precisely - test how many times each app has started.

For this I am using:

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(20,ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);

for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) {
Intent baseIntent = recentTasks.get(i).baseIntent;
if(baseIntent != null) {

Log.d("Text", "Application executed: " + i + ": baseIntent: " + baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName() + baseIntent.getComponent().getClassName());

        }
```

The problem is that it is not enough. Because if an app started 3 times I will only get it once.

For this I need to know when the app got started.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this after two years: but in case its useful to you: Check **my** answer here.

[Android how to know an app has been started and range apps priority according the starting times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875099/andriod-how-to-know-an-app-has-been-started-and-range-apps-priority-according-th/20875971#20875971)

Using the list **taskinfo**, which contains all the currently running apps, you can probably keep counts in shared preferences for *each* app you want to track. Thus you could monitor recent apps and how many times they start.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to read the logs from the logcat
and you can easily find our whenever a activity is getting launch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yeah i know, This is how it was implemented before. 
The problem with that is that its heavy reading a log of several hours. or more disturbing is that the log is different from one device to another and it might change in future versions...

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.sample;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
         List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = mgr.getRecentTasks(100,ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED );
         for(Iterator i = recentTasks.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
            {
            RecentTaskInfo p = (RecentTaskInfo)i.next();     
        String output=p.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName();
                al.add(output);
            }

        Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // write on SD card file data in the text box
                try {

                    Log.e("DEBUG", "Recently started tasks");
                    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("/sdcard/sdcard/Notes/task.txt");  
                    BufferedWriter outStream = new BufferedWriter(outFile); 
                    for (int k = 0; k < al.size(); k++)  
                    {
                        outStream.write(al.get(k));
                    outStream.write("\n");

                    }
                    outStream.close(); 
                   // System.out.println("Data saved."); 
                 }

        //outStream.write(output);
        //al.add
                        //outStream.write("\n");

                                          //  outStream.close(); 



        catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }// onClick
            });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }}
```