# Android how to know an app has been started and range apps priority according the starting times

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

In Android, how does one know an app has been started. I want to detect all apps installed when it starts, and range apps' priority according to its using times. Is there a solution to suggest to do this?

I know using broadcast, but is there some Intent send out from ActivityManager when app had been started, and how to detect this Intent in code? Any other solution is welcome, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First part**:

If you know the package name of your app, try this (*put this following snippet in the onCreate method of your app*):

```
 ActivityManager am= (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Then,

```
 boolean exit = false;
 while(!exit)
 { 
      List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
      ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
     if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals("Your package name"))
     {
      //Do your work here
      exit = true;
     }
 }
```

When you start your app, this will be put into **componentInfo**. The **taskInfo.get(0).topActivity** will return the activity in the foreground. Hence you can know that your app has been started by comparing package using the second code snippet.

**Note**:Put this second code snippet in an *Asynctask* so that the checking of whether the app has started can be done in the *background*.

**Second part:**

To get the priorities, I think  you can do it by checking the list **TaskInfo** which will contain all the running apps.

Comment: Will the above code work for API level above 21? I have tried but doesn't work with API Level 22 and 23.
Please guide.

Comment: Do you get exception? Explain in detail what happens

Comment: No, we didn't get exception but we get package name blank. However we have done it using AccessibilityService. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27642535/1365460

Comment: now a days getRunningTasks is not working on android OS7