# How to monitor all running apps activities lifecycles and crashes?

Tags: android, android-activity, monitor

I'm trying to create a monitor service which would know when apps [start/resume/restart/pause/...](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and also when apps crashes.

I have tried to read logcat, but it seems that calls to [onCreate()/onStart()/onRestart()/...] are not logged into logcat.

Is there a way to catch all these method calls for all running apps ? Is there a way to know when an app crash ?

Note: The service don't need to be notified as soon as these events happens, few seconds/minutes after is also okay.

Comment: you should be more clear of what's your main purpose. Is it crash tracking? Or jsut activity's lifecycle methods tracking? I'm going to add an answer for crash tracking now. but please update your answer. thanks

Comment: @ersentekin The main purpose is tracking all apps life's event, crashes are just another type of death event for my purpose.

Comment: This question has been asked, in various forms, numerous times. The answer is: No, it isn't possible to do this because there are no system events broadcast or logged for activity lifecycle changes.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my code in this answer:

[Android how to know an app has been started and range apps priority according the starting times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875099/andriod-how-to-know-an-app-has-been-started-and-range-apps-priority-according-th/20875971#20875971)

You can monitor it as follows:

If an app is in the foreground, that is if it is in **start**, then it will be the first item of the List **taskInfo**.

If it is **paused**, it will no longer be the first item in that list.

To check **resume**, see if it previously was **not** the first item, but , in the current iteration, it *is* the first item.

I am not too sure about the *crash* part, but maybe you can find a similar way from the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com) for crash tracking. You can see crashed lines in methods as well.

Comment: This solution doesn't apply to my problem, I need to watch ALL apps, not only my application.

Comment: You mean that you want to track all apps downloaded into your device even you did not developed, right?