# How to check if certain intent has started

Tags: android

How to check if intent or app has started ?

My use case is I am showing up notifications through my app and I want to clear them all via `myBuilder.cancelAll()` if default messaging app has started since my app shows sms notifications. So I am kind of looking for something like:

```
if (smsAppStarted) {
  myBuilder.cancelAll();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115493/android-dynamicly-get-the-current-activity-in-foreground, dont know if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To check if an app has started:**

Get the **package name** of the sms app you want to check.

Then refer to **my answer** here:
[Android how to know an app has been started and range apps priority according the starting times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875099/andriod-how-to-know-an-app-has-been-started-and-range-apps-priority-according-th/20875971#20875971)

By using that code, the list **taskInfo** will contain the list of all apps currently running. Search that list using the package name of the sms app. If it is present in that list, it means that *that app* has **started** and *currently running*.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you need to determine, if another app is currently running. If so, then use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212992/how-can-i-check-if-an-app-running-in-android).