# how to detect when Music is played using Native Music Player?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-music-player

I am making an app in which I've made a Service which plays Music from URLs. The thing is that my music Service is playing music correctly *BUT* when user plays any song with Native music player then BOTH(Native Player and My Music Service) are playing music simultaneously. I want to stop My Music Service when user started playing music with native player.

- Is there any Broadcast `Intent` which i can register to Detect the
  music player is started?
- Is it possible to detect Music player Started?
- Any Other Solution?

Any suggestions would appreciated.

Comment: I have a solution if you are OK with your app stopping its music if user *opens* native music app ( but not necessarily starts playing music thru native app). Please let me know if that scenario is OK for you. If it is, I will post answer.

Comment: @Gautham please suggest solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest a different approach, that I believe it's the correct approach.

the issue on your approach is that you're suggesting to check for one specific app. And there're tons of different music players, plus radio players, plus video players, plus games... and all of those should stop your music in case they want to play something.

So how you do it?

It's all explained in the [Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html#HandleFocusLoss).
You have to register an `OnAudioFocusChangeListener`, so, whenever a different app request to have the audio focus, your app can stop the music.

Comment: I was waiting for ans like this, very helpful

Comment: Such a simple solution!! Nice one!!

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Detect if the user has opened native music app. For this , you need to know the *package name* of your *native music app*.

Then refer to my answer here: [Android how to know an app has been started and range apps priority according the starting times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875099/andriod-how-to-know-an-app-has-been-started-and-range-apps-priority-according-th/20875971#20875971)

Using that , the list **taskinfo** will have the list of all running activities, and as explained there, the first element of the list will be the activity in the **foreground**.

**STEP 2:** Once you detect native music app being activated using **STEP 1** (by polling for it in the background) , then stop **your** app's service.

**NOTE**: You should do this in a background (using *asynctask*) or another *service*.

**NOTE 2**: The limitation of this method is that you can't actually stop the music player when the user clicks **play** in the native music app, since this method will help you detect only if the native music app is *opened* or not.

Comment: How about music played from Widget?
What if user played music using any third party music player?

Comment: It will work for third party music player, ( again you need to get package name), I am not sure about widget though.

Comment: I think it will not work in case of widget:), however your suggestion is good, I'll accept your ans if no other best solution is found.

Comment: Sure. I will try and find a solution for that too if possible. :)

Comment: I think you can detect music widget. If you select play, it should be launching the native music app's task. So also find out which *task* is in the foreground when you play music widget, and poll for that task.

Comment: It should be present in a member of **taskinfo** itself. Just check